# ansi c: pipe to gnuplot under windows

Tags: windows, pipe, gnuplot

hope you able to help me with this problem.

I have been using gnu plot under linux with no problems, but atm I'm working on a project for windows.

I have installed gnuplot 4.6 for windows and added gnuplot/bin to my system path.
My code compiles and runs, but gnuplot isn't showing any graphs.

my code look something like this:

```
FILE *pipe = _popen("pgnuplot -persist","w");
fprintf(pipe, "set title \"%s\"\n",plotname); 
fprintf(pipe,"plot '-' with lines\n");

for(i = 0; i < alot ;i++)
{
    fprintf(pipe, "%d %d \n", i, data[i]); 
}

fprintf(pipe, "e");
fflush(pipe);
fclose(pipe);
```

I've tried using the '-noend' command, setting the terminal to windows and using wgnuplot.exe etc. but haven't had any luck so far.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Kind regards

Comment: didn't know that popen works on windows. this involves multiple steps and any of them could make trouble. try to reduce your problem to find out where exactly the problem is: check that the _popen call works by using a simple command, e.g. some test script that creates a file. Check for errors of the _popen function. Specify the absolute path to pgnuplot.exe. Use a simple plot command like "plot x".